# How can we find the distribution of the random variable defined in piece-wise?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

> Find
>   the distribution function of the random variable defined as follows,
>
> [image]
>
> Let, $\Omega = [0, 3]$  and $\Bbb P$ is probability on $\Omega$.

I guess, this question wants me to find out CDF of $X$.

**How should I solve this?**

$\int_0^1(2\omega+1) d\omega = 2 ---------------------(i)$

$\int_1^2(\omega^2-1) d\omega = \frac{4}{3} ---------------------(ii)$

$(i)+(ii)+3 = (2 + \frac{4}{3}+3) = \frac{19}{3}$ Ans.

**Am I getting somewhere?**

I guess, **No.**

Comment: You haven't fully specified the probability measure on $\Omega$. Is it the uniform distribution? If so then you are pretty much OK except that you didn't divide by the normalization constant (3) and you have a $2$ in the second integral which shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Ian, `You haven't fully specified the probability measure on $\Omega$.  Is it the uniform distribution?` --- This is what I have from my instructor. So, I guess, **YES**, this a uniform distribution. `you didn't divide by the normalization constant (3)` --- Please, show me how to do that. `you have a 2 in the second integral which shouldn't be there.`  --- what should be there?

Comment: If the distribution is uniform, then you integrate not against just $dw$ but against $dw/3$ (so that the total probability is $1$). The extra $2$ is in $2\omega^2-1$ which should be just $\omega^2-1$.

Comment: @Ian, Oh, that 2 was a typo. I copied the previous line.